# PHP auto suggest tutorial error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, typeahead.js

I was following the auto suggest videos series by phpacademy on YouTube but got stuck at this point and can't seem to find what wen wrong:

Here's my form:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 <script src="scripts/typeahead.js"></script>
                 <script src="scripts/searchScript.js"></script> 
                 <form action="index.php" method="GET">
                 <input type="text" name="user" id="header-query"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
                 </form>
```

Here's my searchScript.js

```
$(function(){

var users = new Bloodhound({
   datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
   queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitepsace,
   remote: 'inc/search.inc.php?query=%QUERY'
}); 

users.initialize();

$('#header-query').typeahead({
   hint: true,
   highlight: true,
   minlength: 3
}, {
   name: 'user',
   displaykey: 'name',
   source: users.ttAdapter()
});

});
```

I get the following error on my firefox console:

```
Error: datumTokenizer and queryTokenizer are both required


...,""),isReady:!0,error:function(a){throw new Error(a)},noop:function(){},isFuncti...

On Jquery.min.js(line2, col 1820)
```

Comment: Just pointing this out. If there is an error on `jquery.min.js` it means your code varies from the syntax. and since it says `both are required`

Comment: @MAgeshKumaar I know that, but where is it? That's what I can't find out.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

It seems that you misspelled the js file inclusion

Currently it is:

```
<script src="scripts/typahead.js"></script>
```

It should be

```
<script src="scripts/typeahead.js"></script>
```

To further solve the problem rather include the [**typeahead.bundle.js**](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js) script. I think you might be missing the bloodhound.js code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: datumTokenizer and queryTokenizer are both required
 

...,""),isReady:!0,error:function(a){throw new Error(a)},noop:function(){},isFuncti...

 
jquery.min.js (line 2, col 1820)